# PHP SimpleXMLElement slash in elements

Tags: php

I have  a string like these ($_POST['output_xml'):

```
<process>
  <path>/var/somepath/</path>
</process>
```

The output should be formatted as xml an written to a file:

```
header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8",true);
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
$xml_data = $_POST['output_xml'];
$fp = fopen("xml_output.xml","w");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_data);
fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
fclose($fp);
```

I get an error because of the slash in the path element. How so I solve this?

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? And what's the code that generates the said error message?

Comment: Error: String could not be parsed as XML

Comment: Not sure but you can try CDATA :
`<path><![CDATA[/var/somepath/]]></path>` but can you show the entire code plz ?

Comment: I put the whole code in my question....

Comment: SimpleXML parses the XML code shown just fine, without any errors. (And there is no reason why a slash inside of an element’s text content should be a problem.) So _your_ error must be in something you have not shown us yet.

Comment: Thx for the replies and sorry, I had some curved brackets in the string: <process><WSCall (SOA)><path>/var/somepath/</path></WSCall (SOA)></process>...the issue were the curved brackets.....

Answer (score 0):

I have made some tests here and the only situation that PHP don't told me wich node have caused the parsing problem was when the $xml_data varialble was empty try to check this variable content.

Comment: The output of "echo $xml_data" is: <process><path>/var/somepath/</path></process>.

Comment: Try to do that: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);` and look in the source code of the page, maybe you see some especial chars that's could be the problem. Can you post the E_WARNING message for us? –  diogobr07